# Stopping JS in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

How can i stop the following script from running in IE8/9? For some reason sometimes the sections are fading in and sometimes not so i'd prefer to just turn it off in IE8/9.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);

            }

        }); 

    });

});
```

Comment: use `<!--[if gt IE 9]><script>...</script><![endif]-->`

Comment: Only issue is that this is within a separate JS file and i don't think you can put the script tags inside a JS file? I'm not really sure though.

Comment: You can link that script within the conditional comments ...

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function

```
function IEVersion() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var msie = userAgent.indexOf("msie ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number
           return parseFloat((userAgent.match(/.*(?:rv|ie)[\/: ](.+?)([ \);]|$)/) || [])[1]);

   return false;
}
```

to detect MS IE version, You may find the details on below Microsoft support site:

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/167820

and you have to use it with your code as the following

```
function IEVersion() {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var msie = userAgent.indexOf("msie ");

    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number
           return parseFloat((userAgent.match(/.*(?:rv|ie)[\/: ](.+?)([ \);]|$)/) || [])[1]);

   return false;
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    var ie = IEVersion();
    if(ie == false or (ie != 8 and ie != 9))
         your_code();

    function your_code() {
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        /* Check the location of each desired element */
        $('.hideme').each( function(i){

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
            if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ){

                $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);

            }

        }); 

    });
   }

});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but how would i then code in the result to my existing function? As i am thinking i need to get the result of the above function so my original script only runs if it's not IE.